# Is paddingFactor make my update slow?

Tags: performance, mongodb, padding, updates

I have a mongodb instance ,db name:"**bnccdb**" ,collection name:"**AnalysedLiterture**" ,document size:**6 million**.And also ,there is always a **lightweight background daemon** process which is used to crawl data from the internet and insert into this collection(the insert frequency is very low,about 1-2 documents is inserted per second,so have little influence on db performance).I used db.AnalysedLiterature.stats() to
see this collection's configuration information:
[image]

.It show that the **paddingFactor** is very close to **2.0**.

And now , I have another process, which operation is adding two keys to each document in this collection.But it is a pity that the update operation is extremely slow.It really make me confused.When this update process run,the mongostat output is:
[image]

you can see that the result of  **faults** and **locked db**  is really high ,it means that database workload is really high.

I really cannot get the reason.I doubt ,since there is always a lightweight daemon process inserting data to this collection ,so the mongodb **change the paddingFactor from 1 to a larger value(1.9..)**.And since **paddingFactor** is very high , every time my process do update operations(adding two keys to each document),db will reclaim disk space for the padding , thus make a big read/write overhead.
Anyone can give me some suggestion?
Please.

Comment: Your updates are slow because you have 25 indexes on this collection.  Your inserts are slow for the same reason.  You have under 5GB resident in RAM and you have 30GB of indexes (and 20GB in data).  Why would you expect it to be fast when you have so much page faulting?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for your padding factor being so high is because of your updates. MongoDB uses this value to "over allocate" space for documents so that they can be updated and grown in place without needing to be moved to a larger space within MongoDBs storage system. This means that your updates have been growing the documents, requiring that they be pulled out from their existing space on disk and moved to another new larger space. The old space is left behind for re-use, but often these are not re-used as efficiently as they can be.

A padding factor of 2 would mean that MongoDB is allocating twice the space needed for each document, suggesting that your system has performed a very large number of updates and moves.

You should look to enable [powerOf2Sizes](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/reference/command/collMod/#usePowerOf2Sizes), which will make your space allocations uniform and thus make space re-use better. Once you have enabled this setting you should resync or repair your database to rebuild it from scratch as the new allocation system will only effect new documents.

Comment: I really doubt this solution because my userFlags is previously 1 ,not 0.I set it to 0 to test if this will make update faster.But I never repaired my database yes.So ,I will at first set the userFlags to 1 and then I repair the db?Since my db is a single instance ,not a cluster,I don't need to resync ,right?

Comment: If you have a single instance, then yes. You will need to repair rather than resync. Your issue relates to the moving of documents in storage, which is an expensive task compared to two updates. Additionally, all the pagefaulting indicates that MongoDB is pulling your data from disk in order to fulfil queries/updates. This will also be a strong contributor to the delays

Comment: I have don't as you told me .I believe the problem has already solved because of your solution.Thank you very much.